# Android (Java): Show Progress-bar while Loading table view data

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a block of code to load a table view. But for large data, my app is crashing. I want to fix that and also want to show a progress bar while loading the table view data. I tried with the `AsyncTask` but it is showing `Skipped 98 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread`.

My onCreate code (Updated): -

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sheet);

        myDb = new DBHelper(this);
        loadIntentInputs();
        setToolbar();

        new MyWorker(this).execute();
    }
```

My AsyncTask code (Updated): -

```
public class MyWorker extends AsyncTask < String , Context , Void > {
        private Context context ;
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        public MyWorker (Context context) {
            this.context = context ;
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog ( context ) ;
            progressDialog.setCancelable ( false ) ;
            progressDialog.setMessage ( "Retrieving data..." ) ;
            progressDialog.setTitle ( "Please wait" ) ;
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate ( true ) ;
        }

        @ Override
        protected void onPreExecute ( ) {
            progressDialog.show () ;
        }

        @ Override
        protected Void doInBackground ( String ... params ) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    showAttendanceTable();
                }
            });
            return null ;
        }

        @ Override
        protected void onPostExecute ( Void result ) {
            if(progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()){
                progressDialog.dismiss ( ) ;
            }
        }
    }
```

showAttendanceTable method code (Updated): -

```
private void showAttendanceTable() {
        TableLayout tableLayout = findViewById(R.id.table_layout);
        int day_in_month = getDayInMonth(month_year);
        int row_size = sid_array.length+1;
        TableRow[] rows = new TableRow[row_size];
        TextView[] rolls_tv = new TextView[row_size];
        TextView[] names_tv = new TextView[row_size];
        TextView[][] status_tv = new TextView[row_size][day_in_month+1];
        for (int i = 0; i < row_size; i++) {
            rolls_tv[i] = new TextView(this);
            names_tv[i] = new TextView(this);
            for (int j = 1; j <= day_in_month; j++) {
                status_tv[i][j] = new TextView(this);
            }
        }

        // for excel file
        HSSFSheet hssfSheet = null;
        try {
            hssfSheet = hssfWorkbook.createSheet(month_year);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        HSSFRow hssfRow;

        // setting 1st row
        rolls_tv[0].setText("Roll");
        names_tv[0].setText("Name");

        // setting excel file
        hssfRow = hssfSheet.createRow(0);
        hssfRow.createCell(0).setCellValue("Roll");
        hssfRow.createCell(1).setCellValue("Name");

        rolls_tv[0].setTextSize(1,22);
        names_tv[0].setTextSize(1,22);

        rolls_tv[0].setTypeface(rolls_tv[0].getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
        names_tv[0].setTypeface(names_tv[0].getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
        rolls_tv[0].setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        names_tv[0].setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        rolls_tv[0].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF000000"));
        names_tv[0].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF000000"));

        for (int i = 1; i <=day_in_month ; i++) {
            String date = String.valueOf(i);
            if(i<10) date = "0"+date;
            status_tv[0][i].setText(date);

            // setting excel file
            hssfRow.createCell(i+1).setCellValue(date);

            status_tv[0][i].setTextSize(1,22);
            status_tv[0][i].setTypeface(status_tv[0][i].getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
            status_tv[0][i].setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
            status_tv[0][i].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF000000"));
        }

        // setting rows after 1st row
        for (int i = 1; i < row_size ; i++) {
            rolls_tv[i].setText(roll_array[i-1]);
            names_tv[i].setText(name_array[i-1]);

            // setting excel file
            hssfRow = hssfSheet.createRow(i);
            hssfRow.createCell(0).setCellValue(roll_array[i-1]);
            hssfRow.createCell(1).setCellValue(name_array[i-1]);

            rolls_tv[i].setTextSize(1,20);
            names_tv[i].setTextSize(1,20);
            rolls_tv[i].setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
            names_tv[i].setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
            rolls_tv[i].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF000000"));
            names_tv[i].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF000000"));

            int count=0;
            for (int j = 1; j <=day_in_month ; j++) {
                String day = String.valueOf(j);
                String month = month_year.substring(0,3);
                String year = month_year.substring(4,8);
                String status = myDb.getStatus(sid_array[i-1],day+" "+month+" "+year);
                if (status!=null && status.equals("A")) {
                    status_tv[i][j].setText(status);
                    status_tv[i][j].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#EF9A9A"));

                    // setting excel file
                    hssfRow.createCell(j+1).setCellValue(status);

                } else if (status!=null && status.equals("P")) {
                    status_tv[i][j].setText(String.valueOf(++count));
                    status_tv[i][j].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#A5D6A7"));

                    // setting excel file
                    hssfRow.createCell(j+1).setCellValue(String.valueOf(count));
                }

                status_tv[i][j].setTextSize(1,20);
                status_tv[i][j].setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
                status_tv[i][j].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF000000"));
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < row_size; i++) {
            rows[i] = new TableRow(this);

            rolls_tv[i].setPadding(20,12,20,12);
            names_tv[i].setPadding(20,12,20,12);

            if (i==0) {
                rows[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFD400"));
            } else if(i%2==0) {
                rows[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#EEEEEE"));
            } else {
                rows[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E4E4E4"));
            }
            rows[i].addView(rolls_tv[i]);
            rows[i].addView(names_tv[i]);

            for (int j = 1; j <=day_in_month ; j++) {
                status_tv[i][j].setPadding(20,12,20,12);
                rows[i].addView(status_tv[i][j]);
            }
            tableLayout.addView(rows[i]);
        }
        tableLayout.setShowDividers(TableLayout.SHOW_DIVIDER_MIDDLE);
    }
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is you are running new thread on your doInBackground method and you have placed your  showAttendanceTable() code inside runOnUiThread() which is causing too many work to consume main thread.Just copy paste the below code, replace it with your doInBackground() method and everything will work fine.

```
     protected Void doInBackground ( String ... params ) {
     
                showAttendanceTable();
            }
        return null ;
    }
```

Copy this much part of your code from showAttendanceTable() to onPreExecute() method:

```
 TableLayout tableLayout = findViewById(R.id.table_layout);
    int day_in_month = getDayInMonth(month_year);
    int row_size = sid_array.length+1;
    TableRow[] rows = new TableRow[row_size];
    TextView[] rolls_tv = new TextView[row_size];
    TextView[] names_tv = new TextView[row_size];
    TextView[][] status_tv = new TextView[row_size][day_in_month+1];
    for (int i = 0; i < row_size; i++) {
        rolls_tv[i] = new TextView(this);
        names_tv[i] = new TextView(this);
        for (int j = 1; j <= day_in_month; j++) {
            status_tv[i][j] = new TextView(this);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I reposted my problem with details.

Comment: Check my updated answer

Comment: Now it is showing - `ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`

Comment: Sorry i didnt noticed that u r updating ui on your background thread.

Comment: You have to update all your ui in your main thread not on your background thread.